# Dependency not found when added to Flink lib folder

Tags: apache-flink

Hello Flink Community,

following the documentation to troubleshoot unloading of dynamically loaded classes in Flink I added the database driver library to the opt/flink/lib folder on both the Flink JobManager Container and TaskManager Containers running on K8s (Flink Session Cluster, version: 1.11).

I marked the library as provided in my build.sbt file.
The rest of the user code is p[art of the fat jar build by sbt assembly.

Now when I submit a job to the flink cluster using the Flink API (upload and run endpoints) it won't accept the job due to the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
```

Why is the jar not picked up by the Flink classloader?

I even added the class pattern to the config option without any difference:

```
classloader.parent-first-patterns-additional: com.vertica.jdbc.;
```

Link: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/ops/debugging/debugging_classloading.html#unloading-of-dynamically-loaded-classes-in-user-code

Any recommendation would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Possibly duplicated : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65166616/adding-custom-dependencies-for-a-plugin-in-a-flink-cluster/65169620#65169620

Comment: @Tamir1989 Sorry, not a duplicate, as the vertica jdbc driver is not a plugin. Already tried the solution adviced in the answer you posted. It does not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm your jdbc maven dependency is not provided.
when the library is provided, the library is active when compile and test.

Comment: I'm using SBT and the dependency is set to provided to make sure it is not included in the FatJar build by sbt assembly. I'm doing that because I have an issue with class unloading. In the documentation (link posted above it is adviced to not include jdbc drivers into the fat jar to make sure they are only loaded once)